# How do I use a GPG key when publishing a release to Sonatype Nexus via GitHub actions

Tags: gradle, github-actions, sonatype

I've set up a repository in the Maven Central Repository via Sonatype, and now I'm trying to create a GitHub action that will automatically publish an updated version when I create a new release on GitHub.

I know how to create the trigger using the `on:` clause and run the `gradlew publish` task, but I don't know how to supply GitHub with the GPG encryption key needed for it.

How do I do it?

My progress so far is [here](https://github.com/TheOnlyTails/LootTables/blob/main/.github/workflows/publishing.yml).

Comment: You could add the GPG key as a github secret on the repository to use it in your workflow.

Comment: I did that, but I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

[Your issue seems similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61096521/how-to-use-gpg-key-in-github-actions)

**Summarizing**:

GitHub Actions is basically a container that runs commands, you can *define your key as a secret on your project and then importing it in your Github Action workflow*

Here are the steps that could be used on a project to publish the generated artifacts to Sonatype's repository:

- On a terminal window, you can search for the key ID by e-mail: `gpg --list-secret-keys user@example.com`
- Export your key as Base64: `gpg --export-secret-keys YOUR_ID_HERE | base64 > private.key`
- In your Github project, create a new Secret named **GPG_SECRET_KEY** (for example) and paste the Base64 content of your key ([here is a reference how to do it](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets))
- In your workflow `.yml` file, include a step to import the key from your just defined secret like the example below:

```
- name: Configure GPG Key
  run: |
    mkdir -p ~/.gnupg/
    printf "$GPG_SIGNING_KEY" | base64 --decode > ~/.gnupg/private.key
    gpg --import ~/.gnupg/private.key
  env:
    GPG_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.GPG_SECRET_KEY }}
```

*Note: Your GPG Key can't be protected by a password.*