# Can I decrypt an asymmetric PGP encrypted file in github actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, gnupg, pgp

Here is my problem, I'm using [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/), which is underlying using gpg, to encrypt secrets in my application (something like `gpg -e -r user@domain --batch --quiet --yes --compress-algo=none --no-encrypt-to --use-agent` if I'm not wrong). I can decrypt the file in my local machine with pass and with gpg itself but when I try to use the same commands inside github actions it does nothing and just returns blank, I've tested decrypting a symmetric encrypted file and it works so I'm thinking that the gpg version inside ubuntu in github actions is somewhat unable to decrypt asimmetric encrypted files, but why? Am I missing something?

I have the same secret key imported in Github actions as said in [How to use GPG key in github actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61096521/how-to-use-gpg-key-in-github-actions) response.

Thanks